# How to handles parameters in nested routes in express js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been experimenting with nested routes as they are convenient in passing on variables

```
router.post('/postlinkone', function(req, res, next){
 //define few variables (x,y)
 //render or redirect to close this route
   router.post('/postlinktwo', function(req, res, next){
          //use (x,y)
          //render or redirect
   }
}
```

The problem is that express is able to pass on the variables (x,y) during initialization to postlinktwo however these variables are not refreshed in next cycles. Is there a way to hard refresh them or is there a easier way to pass variables

Comment: This isn't the way to do this. Store your variables in a session or use [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html).

Comment: @BenFortune: Is there a way to transfer view models of previous route in request form to new route?

Answer (score 0):

Express has the philosophy of building on the `req` object.

Instead of nesting routes, have independent routes that modify `req`, altering stuff that you want.

```
router.get('/routeOne', function(req, res, next) {
    // do something 
    req._data = {};

    req._data.x = 'bla bla';

    // call next to move to the next route middleware
    next();
});

router.get('/routeOne', function(req, res, next) {
    // check if the params are still there.
    console.log(req._data);
});
```

Comment: I was under impression that if we use these as middlewares we can't render or redirect separate views for RouteOne & RouteTwo. Is this a right assertion?

Comment: You can render/redirect in middlewares. Middlewares are nothing special. They are just functions with the following signature, `function (req, res, next)`

Comment: Rendering and Redirecting are breaking the headers. This way I can't use req._data.x in routeTwo which was previously created in routeOne